# How to disable "ui-switch" in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am not able to disable my `ui-switch` under certain condition. I tried `[attr.disabled]` but doesn't worked for me. Is there any other way to do it?

```
<ui-switch class="mt-4" checkedLabel="{{'T' | translate}}" size="medium"
                                   uncheckedLabel="{{'F' | translate}}"
                                   formControlName="isApprovalRequired"
                                   [attr.disabled]="(selectedTypeData === 'APPROVAL' ? true : null)"></ui-switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just `[diabled]` not `[attr.disabled]` check the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ui-switch#disabled)

```
<ui-switch checked [disabled]="selectedTypeData === 'APPROVAL' ? true : false"></ui-switch>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-ui-switch-41dwaw)